# How can I generate list using dio post request?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I tried a lot but not able to fix,  following I am trying
My json response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "team_one_id": 1,
            "team_two_id": 2,
            "match_date": "04 Mar 2021",
            "is_started": 0,
            "match_between": "Team1 VS Team2",
            "match_between_nick": "ABC VS XYZ",
            "ground_time": "4:30 pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Model

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:core';
class Matches{
  final int id;
  final String match_date;
  final String match_between;
  final String match_between_nick;
  final String ground_time;
  Matches({
    this.id, 
    this.match_date, 
    this.match_between, 
    this.match_between_nick,
    this.ground_time
  });

  factory Matches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

    return Matches(
      id: parsedJson['id'],
      match_date: parsedJson['match_date'],
      match_between: parsedJson['match_between'],
      match_between_nick: parsedJson['match_between_nick'],
      ground_time: parsedJson['ground_time']
    );
  }
}
```

Getting record using dio which is working fine

```
_getMatchesWithDio() async {
    var dio = Dio();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
    };
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "api_actions": "yes"
    });
    Response response =  await dio.post(
      'http://www.myapiurl.com/project/api.php', 
      data: formData, 
      options: Options(
        headers: {"x-auth": 'xyz' },
      )
    );

    matches = Matches.fromJson(response.data['data']);
    return matches;
  }
```

and following is my future builder

```
SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getMatchesWithDio(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return  ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((single){
                    return Text('saddasd');
                  }).toList()
              );
            }
          }
        )
      )
```

and also I would like to post my error log which I am getting in the terminal

```
I/flutter ( 9314): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9314): The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 9314): _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#1f5e1):
I/flutter ( 9314): A build function returned null.
I/flutter ( 9314): The offending widget is:
I/flutter ( 9314):   FutureBuilder<dynamic>
I/flutter ( 9314): Build functions must never return null.
I/flutter ( 9314): To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return
I/flutter ( 9314): "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return
I/flutter ( 9314): "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
I/flutter ( 9314):
I/flutter ( 9314): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 9314):   FutureBuilder<dynamic> file:///D:/asdasd/asdas/lib/screens/HomeScreen.dart:52:16
I/flutter ( 9314):
I/flutter ( 9314): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9314): #0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:302:7)
I/flutter ( 9314): #1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:323:4)
I/flutter ( 9314): #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:7)
I/flutter ( 9314): #3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
I/flutter ( 9314): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
I/flutter ( 9314): #5      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2730:33)
I/flutter ( 9314): #6      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:913:20)
I/flutter ( 9314): #7      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
I/flutter ( 9314): #8      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
I/flutter ( 9314): #9      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
I/flutter ( 9314): #10     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
I/flutter ( 9314): #14     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:251:10)
I/flutter ( 9314): #15     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:3)
I/flutter ( 9314): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 9314):
I/flutter ( 9314): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9314): Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null.
```

Kindly guide me where I am wrong so that I can fix the issue. I would like to appreciate.

Thank you so much

Comment: you have two `if`s inside `build` method - if none of them are `true` the `null` is returned (i would bet that `snapshot.hasError` is `true` :-( in your case)

Comment: @pskink sure, how can I fix it, would you please explain. I am new to flutter. Thanks

Comment: check `snapshot.error` - the best solution in such cases is `print(snapshot)` as the first line of your `builder` callback

Comment: @pskink I did `print(snapshot)` which is returning `I/flutter ( 9314): AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')`

Comment: so this is your error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` - what is `response.data` ? try to `print(...)` it

Comment: @pskink can you please help? I am new to flutter

Comment: @pskink `response.data` has that json which I mentioned in the question

Comment: did you `print(...)` it just after `Response response =  await dio.post`?

Comment: @pskink I just did it, it is returning this `I/flutter ( 9314): {data: [{id: 1, team_one_id: 1, team_two_id: 2, match_date: 04 Mar 2021, is_started: 0, match_between: Royal Challengers Bangalore VS Chennai Super Kings, match_between_nick: RCB VS CSK, ground_time: 4:30 pm}]}`

Comment: so `factory Matches.fromJson` is called with a `List` not a `Map` - to be sure, before `matches = Matches.fromJson(response.data['data']);` call `print(response.data['data'].runtimeType)` - it should print `List` and not `Map`

Comment: @pskink yes it is `List<dynamic>` returns

Comment: thats why you have an error: you are passing a `List` to `fromJson()` method that accepts a `Map`: i mean `factory Matches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)`

Comment: @pskink I understood now can you please guide me how can I fix it

Comment: sorry, this is your job

Comment: your question was `Build functions must never return null` - so i explained why it returns `null` - if you have problems with parsing your data please open another question

Comment: @pskink you can give me a fovour by posting answer on this same question as you already know what is my problem. S.O allows only 1 question in 60 minutes. So in this way i will be able to fix and if you want i would edit the title as well. but please help

Comment: ok so first start with changing `factory Matches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> ` to `factory Matches.fromJson(List<dynamic>` and implement your `fromJson` method correctly - i really dont know what you want to do with your data

Comment: @pskink i created static Cards , now I need to make it dynamic by using futurebuilder but I am very weak in modeling and future builder. you already know my json response

Comment: @pskink can you help please

Comment: here you have some code generator based on input json: https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0):

It misses a `return` when you are not in the cases managed by your `if`.

```dart
SafeArea(
  top: true,
  child: FutureBuilder(
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((single) {
          return Text('saddasd');
        }).toList());
      }
      // add a SizedBox for the other case
      return const SizedBox();
    },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response json is list of `Matches` but you decode a list with function for decode single object

you need add this line end of your _getMatchesWithDio() function.

`return List<Matches>.from(response.data['data'])`

and put your return type in your function `List<Matches> _getMatchesWithDio() ...`